# No suitable driver found, SQLException in Java

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans, sqlexception

I have not worked with databases before and wanted to practice with video tutorials, but I immediately get an error.

this is my code: (with database i work in netbeans)

`

```
package javaapplicationdatabase;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Enumeration;


public class JavaApplicationDataBase {
    
public static final String DRIVER_NAME = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
public static final String CONN_STRING = "jdbs:mysql://localhost:3306/?user=root&password=root"; 
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
       Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
       while(drivers.hasMoreElements())  
            System.out.println(drivers.nextElement());   
       
        
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER_NAME);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {            
            System.out.println("MySQL driver not found!");
            return;
        }
       try {
          Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING);
       } catch (SQLException ex) {          
          System.out.println("Cannot open connection!" + ex.getMessage());
          return;
        }
          
    }
    
}
```

`

in libraries of this project i connected mysql-connected.
[connect mysql connected in netbeans project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IImY.png)

I tried to reinstall mysql and write the path to the driver in a different way, but it still gives this error. I read answers to other questions about this error and they all say that you need to connect the jar file, but i have it connected and i don’t know how else to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it is can be typo in your url, try change:

```
jdbs:mysql:
```

to

```
jdbc:mysql:
```

Comment: Consider add database name to your url like 
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YOUR_DB_NAME?user=root&password=root

Comment: I'm ashamed of this mistake :D thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

just add the MySQL JDBC JAR into class path if you are running on Java SE6 and driver is JBC 4.0 compliant, e.g. mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar.